# Windows Azure Mobile Services using Where statement

Tags: android, windows, windows-phone-7, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have in my app this code:

```
Globals.mClient.getTable(Action.class).where()
                                      .field("Id").eq("1")
                                      .execute(new TableQueryCallback<Action>() { ... }
```

But I have a list of IDs and I want get table with items that have the same ID as the IDs in the list.

Like something that:

```
Globals.mClient.getTable(Action.class).where()
                                     .field("Id")
                                     .eq(listID.getItem(0) || listID.getItem(1) || ...)
                                     .execute(new TableQueryCallback<Action>() { ... }
```

Do you know how to do it? Do you understand me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
int[] listIds= {1, 2, 3};
MobileServiceQuery<..> query = Globals.mClient.getTable(Action.class).where();

for (int index = 0; index < listIds.length; index++)
{
   if (index!=0){
       query = query.or();
   }

   query = query.field("Id").eq(listIds[index])
}

query.execute(new TableQueryCallback<Action>() { ... }
```